# Xcode 10 Build Location -> Per-configuration Build Products Path

Tags: react-native, xcode10, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm just trying to implement react-native code push on my react-native application but I just can't find Build Location -> Per-configuration Build Products Path on Xcode 10.

Here's the guide I'm following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native#multi-deployment-testing

Where did that change go to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open Project Navigator
2. Click on Project you need to edit
3. In the pane that opens click on target
4. Click on Build Settings tab
5. Select "All" in the filters
6. Select "Levels" in the filters
7. Search for "Build Location" in search.

[image: How to edit Build Locations]

Comment: I managed to find it but this is indeed the answer. Thank you!

Comment: In **Xcode 11.0** I can find "**Build Location**" but "**Per-configuration Build Products Path**" is missing?

Comment: Looks like it was removed from Xcode 11. Weird, because the [Build settings reference](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/itcaec37c2a6) still has it.

Comment: So how are we going to set this?

Comment: Try setting regular "Build Products Path" instead of "Per-configuration Build Products Path".

Comment: In Xcode12, "User-Defined"  Add "CONFIGURAYION_BUILD_DIR" replace "Per-configuration Build Products Path"

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11 has removed this setting moving to the new build settings found in the **Workspace Settings**.

**For CodePush**, you want to create another user-defined section named *CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR*, using the same per-configuration settings.

[image]

***NOTE: I found that Xcode would crash anytime I set the section name to CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR after creating it (most likely due to the empty values). To avoid this issue, create the section without renaming, set the configuration specific build folders, and then change the name.***

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 11, you can find this option at **PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR**

Comment: This is incorrect. What you have posted is a Pod specific build folder, not anything that alters the derived data folder path.